# Running powershell script through a list of servers

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that outputs iis app pools running on a server along with the dotnet version, username and password running the account. How can i get this working for a list of servers where i can point it to a list of 100 servers on a text file..say servers.txt. Below is the code..

```
try{
Import-Module WebAdministration

$webapps = Get-WebApplication
$list = @()
foreach ($webapp in get-childitem IIS:\AppPools\)
{
$name = "IIS:\AppPools\" + $webapp.name
$item = @{}

$item.WebAppName = $webapp.name
$item.Version = (Get-ItemProperty $name managedRuntimeVersion).Value
$item.State = (Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $webapp.name).Value
$item.UserIdentityType = $webapp.processModel.identityType
$item.Username = $webapp.processModel.userName
$item.Password = $webapp.processModel.password

$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $item
$list += $obj
}

$list | Format-Table -a -Property "WebAppName", "Version", "State", "UserIdentityType", "Username", "Password" | out-file MyDCs.csv

}catch
{
$ExceptionMessage = "Error in Line: " + $_.Exception.Line + ". " + $_.Exception.GetType().FullName + ": " + $_.Exception.Message + " Stacktrace: " + $_.Exception.StackTrace
$ExceptionMessage
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? We can help you work through problems, but we aren't here to just do the work for you.

Comment: I have tried the following  which did not work.                                                                                                                                                      
 $list | Format-Table -a -Property "WebAppName", "Version", "State", "UserIdentityType", "Username", "Password" | export-csv -path c:\result.csv

Comment: That has nothing to do with running the code on multiple servers. That is dysfunctional code trying to output to a CSV file. You would need to change the `Format-Table` to `Select-Object`, and then pass that to `Export-Csv`. What have you tried to make it run against remote servers?